# Change the Font of a Chemical Structure from an .eps file in TexWorks

Tags: chemfig, eps, chemistry, epstopdf, chemschemex

I am currently using TexWorks to write my lab report and I am using an .eps file to show a chemical structure. Below is the code in my report.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.92,center]{michael.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The resulted structure looks like this

[image: Structure Produced by TexWorks]

Can anyone be able to help me get this structure to have the regular ACS 1996 style font? It should look like below. (I apologize for the big size of the second image.)

[image: Ideal Structure]

Comment: I remember that there is a package called `psfrag`; 11 April 1998 - Michael C. Grant and David Carlisle: http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/psfrag/pfgguide.pdf

Comment: I have tried invoking the package but nothing has changed. Can you be able to give an example code?

Comment: @AnTrinh You have to use the package (=read the manual/tutorials how to use it). You can't expect that it does some magic if you just include it. Also, if you have some program for editing eps files (e.g. Adobe Illustrator), just modify the eps there with the font you need.

Comment: @AnTrinh Please attach your EPS file, and please describe what "regular ACS 1996 style font" means.